# value-by-date object modeling in play framework

Tags: model, playframework

I ran into a problem after starting with play framework just a few days ago:

I have two models: Share and ShareValue

simplified Share:

```
@Entity
public class Share extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;
}
```

simplified ShareValue:

```
@Entity
public class ShareValue extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Share share;
    public Date date;
    public double value;
}
```

As shown above ShareValue holds current and historic values of a single share by date.

Now, in most parts of my application - especially when I work with the Share object - I just need the current value of a share, for example to render a list of shares with current values. To render those lists easily it would be very convenient to have the current ShareValue accessible by a simple getter. Also for performance reasons I expect it will be good to initialize the object with this value without having to issue another query on access.

To create a SQL query joining the current value to a share is quite easy, but how do I bind the result to the Share model? Can I add a @OneToOne dependency in the Share object? But how do I specify the current date then?

Or is that impossible and I will add a simple getCurrentValue() method to the Share that issues another query to get the current ShareValue?

I'm somehow lost. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one side of the relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Share extends Model {
    @Required
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "share")
    public List<ShareValue> values;
    
    public ShareValue getLatest(){
        return ShareValue.findLAtest(this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class ShareValue extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Share share;
    public Date date;
    public double value;

    public static ShareValue findLatest(Share share){
       return ShareValue.find("where share = ? order by date desc", share).first();
    }
}
```

Have you looked at the play [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide2)? It's a good starting point if you are not familiar with JPA and Play.

You could also use a sorted set instead of a list to get the share values ordered and return the  latest one.

Comment: Yes. I already tried that and it's fine for iterating over all values of a share - but, as I mentioned above, that is a thing I probably never do from this side of the relationship. Moreover I would like to get only the latest value object when accessing a share, as this is what I need most of the time.

Comment: Updated example with find latest